# Drag a sprite attached to a body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have a `CCSprite` that is attached to body in a `b2world` .
When someone is touch it, i want to move it with the touch location.
With a regular sprite that works fine , but with a sprite that has a body- it does not .
it gets the touch but not move the sprite (the body follow the sprite or the opposite?)
How should i do that ? apply a force relative to the touch is a problem..

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];


    //detect a touch ont the button
    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {

        CGPoint location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: currentPosition];

        CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
        if( tempSprite.tag==2  )
        {

            if(CGRectContainsPoint([tempSprite boundingBox], location))
            {
                tempSprite.position=location;
                NSLog(@"touched");
             }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: mouse joint is best option.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the position of the body using SetTransform function. I think it's looking something like:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];


//detect a touch ont the button
for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{

    CGPoint location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: currentPosition];

    CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
    if( tempSprite.tag==2  )
    {

        if(CGRectContainsPoint([tempSprite boundingBox], location))
        {
            b->SetTransform( b2Vec2( location.x/PTM_RATIO, location.y/PTM_RATIO ), 0 ); //change position of the body
            NSLog(@"touched");
         }
    }

}
```

}

Don't forget, if you want to change body position apply force or set linear velocity you must use kinematic or dynamic body type.